# If post has ANY term attached to it, get the first one only

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am developing a theme that has several custom taxonomy that act as radio buttons.

How do I write a conditional that does...

`if(post_has_any_terms($post->id, 'custom-taxonomy')) { echo $term; }.`

I feel like this should be so simple, but nothing that I have tried works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this.  It might not be the smartest way but it works for me.

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
if(is_array($terms)) { 
        $term = array_shift(array_values($terms)); return $term; 
    } else { $term = "0"; }
```

The page doesn't work if $term = 0, but at least it lets the author know they forgot to check one of the boxes ( since it's required ).